# How do I configure the maximum line width for zig fmt?

Tags: zig

It appears, the zig fmt executed by emacs upon save does not have a limit on characters per line in zig source code.

But I am sure I am not the only one not owning an infinite width monitor...(I usually configure max width of 60, so I can see 2 files next to each other in a readable font size).

In Rust, I can do such settings in `rustfmt.toml` somewhere in a root directory and be happy forthwith. I expected, zig has something similar in place, but I could not find it.

So, "how to do it?", is my humble question.

Comment: see: [zig fmt: prefer vertical formatting when horizontal formatting leads to very long lines](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/3057)

Comment: @Luuk Not sure if your comment applies to zig source code formatting.